# How to update a column of a table to a scaling value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column in my table to use the values 1 through (a max number decided by a count of records).

I don't know if I'm explaining this right, so I set up a SQLFiddle with the data I'm trying to update.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a09ed/8)**

I want to set the Version column to 1 through (the max number).
Is there some way to rewrite this query to a scale the Version number?
As in, I want the first record to use 1, the second record to use 2, and so on...

```
UPDATE Documents
SET Version = 1
```

Comment: Can you post the desired result?, I still don't really get what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a CTE and no joins:

```
with RankedDocument as
(
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (order by ID)
  from Documents
)
update RankedDocument
set Version = rn
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a09ed/32).

Comment: This seems easier to understand than the version that leoinfo posted. It also looks like it would be more efficient because no join is involved.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, you want every record from `Documents` to have a `version` number which is a number moving from 1 ..... N.

You could use a temporary table and `ROW_NUMBER` technique to get the incremental `version` and then `UPDATE` it back to your original table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID int, Version int)

INSERT INTO #Temp (ID, Version)
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)
FROM Documents

UPDATE Doc
SET Version = TT.Version
FROM Documents AS Doc INNER JOIN #Temp AS TT ON Doc.ID = TT.ID

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

If I understand you correctly..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH list AS (
  SELECT
      ID
    , Version = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY VersionID ASC )
  FROM Documents
)
UPDATE d SET  
  d.Version = x.Version
FROM Documents AS d
INNER JOIN list as x ON d.ID=x.ID

SELECT * FROM Documents
```

You can change the order ( ORDER BY VersionID ASC  ) 
to the one you need.

Comment: I used your version, and I think I got it to where I need it. I actually have only been working with SQL since October of last year, and have never heard of ROW_NUMBER(), so thank you for showing me how to use it! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a09ed/48

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a semicolon at the *beginning* of this query?

Comment: That is just a habit I built to avoid getting in trouble... :)  Depending on what is before WITH in your code, the code might fail if the above statement accepts WITH as an argument/option. See "BEGIN TRANSACTION WITH MARK", for example.